# What's wrong with this Google Chart API Bar graph URL?

Tags: google-visualization

The url I'm using is this:

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:|2010-08-06|2010-08-02|2010-08-05|2010-08-03|2010-08-04|1:|0|2347.002|3650|2:|min|average|max&chxp=2,10,50.83,90&chxr=0,2347.002,3650&chxt=x,y,r&chs=200x120&cht=bvg&chco=EBB411&chd=t:3455.01,730,2240,1760,3550&chma=|5&chtt=Revenue
```

The image:

[image]

The bars shouldn't be filling all the way to the top, but I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [documentation on data encoding:](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html#text)

> Basic text-formatted data lets you specify floating point values from 0—100, inclusive, as numbers.

You're supplying numbers bigger than 100, which is why they're going all the way to the top.

For example, if I change one of the supplied data points to 50, it looks like this:

[image]

You need to either include a scaling parameter or used the extended encoding format.